# How to export 3D pointcloud as a rendered Voxel grid?

Tags: meshlab

I have a scene consisting of several colorized voxels. When opening it in meshlab all points are plotted as 2 dimensional squares. Is it possible to render a scene where the squares are replaced by 3D cubes with additional lightning / reflectivity in meshlab?

This is what I'm getting so far:

[image]

I rather want something like this:

[image]

Comment: I was under the impression meshlab isn't intended to be a renderer, it's a tool for editing meshes for eventual use elsewhere. What is your reason for wanting to render the scene with lighting/reflectivity inside meshlab?

Comment: The above example already shows it. After rendering, due to light reflections, one can see the scene much more clearly as in the first example. I also wrote to the author of the paper but they only refer to meshlab without giving any specifics. I recently saw a matlab function that draws small cuboids for every voxel in the grid (still no rendering but it might improve the visibility of some details - I'll try that code if I have time and post the answer here). From the coloring I would say second image seems to originate from meshlab (as does the first one created by me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a voxel plot script for blender.
https://github.com/cagcoach/BlenderPlot/

BlenderPlot takes `.mat` files as input and generates a scene containing the voxel blocks. Afterwords you can render a worderfull image of your data.
FYI you most probably need to adjust the camera position, and the rotation as well as the enlightment by hand.

This is an output created from random data.
[image: BlenderPlot]

Comment: Awesome script, thanks. Here is a small [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/vrxsk6D1KhQ) how I ran the script on some example code